# Creating a column number with the number in the column

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, explode

```
id | ozID  | ozDa1     | ozDa2     |  ozDa3
-----------------------------------------------
 1 | 3,4   | Khar      | Lorem     | Emre
 2 | 1,2   | Imson     | Berkay    | ade  
 3 | 2     | abc       | Goksel    | casc
 4 | 5     | teq       | Insanlik  | fdsc
 5 | 1,5,2 | asd       | Oyle      | asdas
 6 | 2,1   | fav       | Boyle     | dsssa
 7 | 3     | qwrewq    | Filan     | dcsd
```

I can write the content like:

```
$partNameWD->ozDa2; // Berkay
```

But the number at the end can be variable, like this: `ozDa4`.

---

At first I get the data from the `ozID` table, for example: `1,2`

**What does it mean 1,2?**

It points to column numbers: `ozDa1` and `ozDa2`

Access to this number is like this:

```
$ozColNo = explode(",", $partNameWD->ozID);

foreach (ozColNo as $ozColId) {
    echo ozColId." - "; // 1 - 2
}
```

---

**So what is my problem?**

How do I get data from the column with these numbers? So, how can I print the data from one and the second

It has to be transformed: `ozDa1 // Imson` and `ozDa2 // Berkay`

Please can you tell me the method?
Thanks

Comment: Create an associative array,like colname=>1 and use that to compose a query.

Comment: @Mihai Of course this can be but my priority is to protect the structure.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Logically, this could be? `$content = "$partNameWD->ozDa.${$ozColId}";`

Comment: In that case don't use an RDBMS. Bye.

Comment: Probably `$content = $partNameWD->{'ozDa' . $ozColId};` .. But I've never used that crazy stuff.

Comment: @Strawberry Why you use downvote? What is this RDBMS?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel It worked! Is it possible that the negative effect on performance and safety with solution way?

Comment: @J.Doe I would rather worry about the design of your data structure and DB schema than about the performance of that single line of code.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thank you for your time. If you want to write a reply - I will gladly accept

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that I correctly understand the question, but you can get the mapping between "column number" and "column name" in `information_schema.columns`.  So, if you are given a number, you can look up the name using:

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = @table_name and table_schema = @table_schema and
      ordinal_position = @op;
```

You can do a group of columns with a slightly more complicated approach (because I assume ordering is important)

```
select group_concat(c.column_name order by cols.ordering) as columns
from (select 1 as colpos, 1 as ordering union all
      select 2, 2
     ) cols join
     information_schema.columns c
     on c.ordinal_position = cols.colpos
where table_name = @table_name and table_schema = @table_schema;
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$output= $partNameWD->{'ozDa' . $ozColId};
echo $output;
```

Check out the `PHP.net` site for this

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

> Caution
>
> Further dereferencing a variable property that is an array has
>   different semantics between PHP 5 and PHP 7. The PHP 7.0 migration
>   guide includes further details on the types of expressions that have
>   changed, and how to place curly braces to avoid ambiguity.